# Iterating though slightly different models in purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, modelr

I have the following code comparing the rmse of models that differ only in the polynomial term.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
cv_mtcars = mtcars %>%
  crossv_kfold(k = 10)
cv_mtcars %>%
  mutate(model1 = map(train, ~lm(disp ~ wt, data = .)),
         model2 = map(train, ~lm(disp ~I(wt^2), data = .)),
         model3 = map(train, ~lm(disp ~I(wt^3), data = .)),         
         model4 = map(train, ~lm(disp ~I(wt^4), data = .)),
         model5 = map(train, ~lm(disp ~I(wt^5), data = .)),
         model6 = map(train, ~lm(disp ~I(wt^6), data = .)),
        order1 = map2_dbl(model1, test, ~rmse(.x, .y)),
        order2 = map2_dbl(model2, test, ~rmse(.x, .y)),
        order3 = map2_dbl(model3, test, ~rmse(.x, .y)),
        order4 = map2_dbl(model4, test, ~rmse(.x, .y)),
        order5 = map2_dbl(model5, test, ~rmse(.x, .y)),
        order6 = map2_dbl(model6, test, ~rmse(.x, .y))) %>% 
  select(order1,order2,order3,order4,order5,order6) %>% gather(1:6,key=model,value=value) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=factor(model),y=value))+
  labs(y="rmse",x="polynomial",title="Model Assesment",subtitle="disp~I(wt^x)")
```

Is there a more efficient way to iterate through my models? I feel like I am writing more code than I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the models with an outer call to `map` to iterate over the polynomial orders and an inner call to `map` to iterate over the 10 folds. In the code below, I've used `poly(wt, i)` instead of `I(wt^i)`, because `I(wt^i)` generates a polynomial with only the highest-order term, while `poly(wt, i)` generates a polynomial with terms of all orders up to the highest order. I've saved the `rmse` for each fold in the `model_cv` object, but you can, of course, pipe it directly into ggplot instead.

```
set.seed(50)
model_cv = setNames(1:6, 1:6) %>% 
  map_df(function(i) { 
    map2_dbl(cv_mtcars[["train"]], cv_mtcars[["test"]], function(train, test) {
      model = lm(disp ~ poly(wt,i), data=train)
      rmse(model, test)
    })
  }) %>% 
  gather(`Polynomial Order`, rmse)

ggplot(model_cv, aes(`Polynomial Order`, rmse)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", pch="_", colour="red", size=7) +
  labs(title="Model Assesment",subtitle="disp ~ poly(wt, order)")
```

[image]